# ON SSL configuration Session related issue in http and https

Tags: java, http, session, ssl, https

Web.xml

```xml
<security-constraint>
   <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>*</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </web-resource-collection>
   <user-data-constraint>
      <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
   </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Here `<transport-guarantee>` is set to NONE and I am redirecting http to https in standalone.xml. So since value is NONE it wont be redirected to https. But, I can still access some of the parts in http(like I can login). Whereas, there are some pages on which, if I go through http my session gets log out. But when I work with https there are no such issues on those pages. Please explain me what is the reason? I know i might be lacking some concepts of SSL or anything else.

Comment: did you clean your browser's cache ?

Comment: Yes I did and nothing got changed.. @Eugène Adell

Comment: I have found out one more thing that for Https browser stores Jsessionid cookie but for Http there is no Jsessionid cookie stored. This scenario is only for Chrome. I have checked in Internet Explorer there my application doesn't break whether from http or https request is made.

Comment: There is a secure attribute for cookies. When set, only HTTPS is allowed, but I don't know the default behavior of JBOSS (you are using JBOSS, right ?) with this attribute for JSESSIONID cookie.

Comment: I am not setting secure attribute in web.xml for cookies, Yes you are right I am using Jboss. The issue is that JSESSION ID cookie is not stored in chrome browser for http whereas all other browsers don't have such issue.

Comment: If you can see your server sending the session cookie, and Chrome not saving/using it, it's a Chrome bug. Do you see the cookie in the server's response headers ?